# Content type by permissions

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, roles

I've set up different roles and when I add/edit content I want to be able to check who can view this page by simply checking the applicable roles, is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the Node Access module is what you're after - http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

"Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions' permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set default access controls per content type, and also define which roles are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab."